# Android videoview doesn't play in landscape mode

Tags: android, android-layout, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I have an activity that play a video with VideoView. Video starting in onCreate, and starts only if layout is in portrait mode, after it has started i can change to landscape and video continue to playing correctly.

The problem is when starting activity in landscape mode, in this case video doesn't play.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <activity
        android:name="...."
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_fullscreen_rec"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:parentActivityName="...." >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="...." />
    </activity>
```

In onCreate method I simply set videosource and start videoview.

Then I have:

```
    @Override
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
      super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code after the onCreate Method in your activity.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);    
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle state) {
super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);    
}
```

please check this. tell me if this works ?

Comment: I haven't if(portrait) , It can starts in each mode, but now it works only if I start activity and put device in portrait position, after I can rotate device.

Comment: check the possible answer